# Find a unique item based on two values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array called `collection`. This array contains a large number of arrays with a length of 12. Each item of the latter array has - among others - a source ID [0] and target ID [1] (pairs of source and target are unique, but the same source ID can be assigned to different target IDs).

With the source and target IDs given, I need to find the item inside the array with the given IDs and manipulate its values.

jQuery is present if that helps finding the solution.

Thanks in advance!

```
var collection = [
[
    136898,
    162582,
    "8X1ABG\1",
    "lorem ipsum",
    true,
    "FULL",
    true,
    "FULL",
    "8X1ABG\0",
    "dolor sit",
    false,
    "SIMILAR"
],
[
    136898,
    163462,
    "8X1ABG\1",
    "lorem ipsum",
    true,
    "FULL",
    true,
    "FULL",
    "8X1ABG\0",
    "dolor sit",
    false,
    "SIMILAR"
],  
[
    136578,
    161873,
    "8X1A1G\2",
    "lorem ipsum",
    true,
    "FULL",
    true,
    "FULL",
    "8X1A1G\0",
    "dolor sit",
    false,
    "SIMILAR"
],
[
    136432,
    162280,
    "8X1ABC\1",
    "lorem ipsum",
    true,
    "FULL",
    true,
    "FULL",
    "8X1ABC\0",
    "dolor sit",
    false,
    "SIMILAR"
]]



// TODO: find the unique item in collection array with the following source
// and target ID
var sourceId = 136898;
var targetId = 163462;

// TODO: update some values of the identified item inside collection
```

Comment: I'd suggest you change your data structure to an array of objects with named keys. Multi-dimensional arrays like that are a hell to maintain.

Comment: I am using the array to feed a plugin which handles the data output. Unfortunately this plugin needs arrays to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var item = collection.filter(function(collect) {
  return collect[0] == sourceId && collect[1] == targetId;
});
```

Again, like I said in the comments, it would better if you change your data structure to an array of objects with named keys then you can do this much more readable:

```
return collect.sourceId == sourceId && collect.targetId == targetId;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need compatibility to older browsers, since `.filter()` is [supported only by IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you can also loop through the elements of the array(or write the implementation of filter, provided by MDN).

```
var item = [];
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    var coll = collection[i];
    if (coll[0] == sourceId && coll[1] == targetId) item.push(coll);
}
```